# Как интерактивно встроить данные в тег элемента vue.js

Tags: vue.js

```
<div class="user">
    <img src="http//...." alt="photo">
    <p>{{ Some text }}</p>
</div>
```

Подскажите каким образом мне вставить src:{{ ... }}, чтоб она отображалась в DOM ?

Answer (score 3):

Любой атрибут вставляется так `v-bind:src="imageLink"`, либо внутрь можно передать класс `v-bind:class="{ 'active': isActive }"`

Где : imageLink - твоя переменная в компоненте Vue,

В классе добавится только те классы которые будут true (isActive это тоже переменная)

Ну и так можно любой атрибут задавать `v-bind:data-product, v-bind:value`

Comment: Спасибо, круто, все работает